# -bash: otool: command not found, Can you teach bash a default location to look for a command?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, otool

I can find the tool command in my filesystem under:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/otool
```

If I specify that entire path, otool will work.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/otool -tV hello -p _main
```

However, since I have to be inside the folder of the hello.c file I'm referencing, bash won't find otool automatically if I just type

```
otool -tV hello -p _main
```

I've had this same problem with a number of commands. **Is there any way to set up bash so it automatically finds otool (and similar commands), without me having to writing out the entire path name each time?** Thanks!

Note: If it matters, I'm using a Mac.

Note 2: I've read through a ton of the "Command not found" threads but none seem to answer the question of teaching bash where to look for a command by default. I feel like this question should have been answered somewhere, but haven't come across it yet. Since the only programs I'll be working with any time soon will be iOS/Xcode related, this is worthwhile shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

Put this in your `~/.bashrc` to have it persist.

Comment: You need to export it as well.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: not if `PATH` is already exported, which it almost certainly is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to `export` after any change, otherwise the programs will only see the old one.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: you don't. Try it.

Comment: For instance, if I type "PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar; bash", the new shell doesn't have /foo/bar in the path.  If I type "PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar; export PATH; bash", the new shell does have /foo/bar in the path.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: cannot reproduce. Is `PATH` in the environment? `env | grep PATH`

Comment: @Paul Tomblin, once a variable is exported, it stays in that state. There is absolutely no need to "re-export" a variable after a change.

Comment: When I use your command, @larsmans it just appends to the old path. How do I completely replace it or open up ~/.bashrc in a text editor (where is that file located?)

Comment: larsmans: I would suggest instead the safer `PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`

Comment: @Orchid: `~` means in your homedir. And yes, this appends to the old path, because otherwise you couldn't even do `ls` anymore.

Comment: @Orchid, you do not want to replace the PATH.  You need the other values that are already there so that bash can find other programs.

Comment: Regardless of how ugly my PATH looks  what I needed works now! Thank you! Is there anything long term I should be worried about (with regards to my PATH having all those extra path attempts appended together)?

Comment: @Orchid: hardly, except that the entries of `PATH` are searched *in order*, so it's possible to override commands with. Performance shouldn't suffer as the shell caches the paths to commands in a hash table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also Try using alias to do this. e.g.

$ alias otool='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/otool'

You can also add this in your bashrc/profile file.